# What's wrong with pandas.join()?

Tags: python, pandas, join

I try to merge 2 data set of pandas, but it's filling by NaN's.

1st:

```
            _0   _1   _2   _3   _4   _5

2011-01-29  0    0    0    0    0    0
2011-01-30  0    0    0    0    0    0
2011-01-31  0    0    0    0    0    0
2011-02-01  0    0    0    0    0    0
```

2st:

```
              event_type_1      snap_CA      snap_TX      snap_WI

2011-01-29    NaN               0            0            0
2011-01-30    NaN               0            0            0
2011-01-31    NaN               0            0            0
2011-02-01    NaN               1            1            0
```

code that i use:

```
right = main_df
left = calen_df.drop(['wm_yr_wk','weekday','wday',\
               'month','year','d','event_name_1',\
               'event_name_2','event_type_2'], axis=1)\
               .set_index('date')              
left.index.name = ''
left.join(right)
```

and result:

```
              event_type_1      snap_CA         snap_TX        snap_WI   _0  _1  _2  _3  _4  _5

2011-01-29    NaN               0               0               0        NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2011-01-30    NaN               0               0               0        NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2011-01-31    NaN               0               0               0        NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2011-02-01    NaN               1               1               0        NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I can't find out where the problem is?!

Comment: It would help if you would give what code you were using to get this result: exactly how are you calling `merge`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have no problem to join example data from your question. Maybe first use `print()` to check if you have to same data when you join them.

Comment: The problem is in your expectations, so say what you expected & why.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your DataFrames (or at least one) are different in some respect
from what you presented in your post.

Start from such a test:

```
txt1 = '''    event_type_1      snap_CA      snap_TX      snap_WI
2011-01-29    NaN               0            0            0
2011-01-30    NaN               0            0            0
2011-01-31    NaN               0            0            0
2011-02-01    NaN               1            1            0'''
txt2 = '''    _0   _1   _2   _3   _4   _5
2011-01-29  0    0    0    0    0    0
2011-01-30  0    0    0    0    0    0
2011-01-31  0    0    0    0    0    0
2011-02-01  0    0    0    0    0    0'''
left_t  = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt1), sep=r'\s+', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
right_t = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt2), sep=r'\s+', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Then `print(left_t)`. The result should be:

```
            event_type_1  snap_CA  snap_TX  snap_WI
2011-01-29           NaN        0        0        0
2011-01-30           NaN        0        0        0
2011-01-31           NaN        0        0        0
2011-02-01           NaN        1        1        0
```

Note that the above printout does **not** contain any empty line after the
title row.

The same printout for *right_t* should yield:

```
            _0  _1  _2  _3  _4  _5
2011-01-29   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-01-30   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-01-31   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-02-01   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

also without any empty row after column names.

And finally run `print(left_t.join(right_t))`. The result I got was:

```
            event_type_1  snap_CA  snap_TX  snap_WI  _0  _1  _2  _3  _4  _5
2011-01-29           NaN        0        0        0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-01-30           NaN        0        0        0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-01-31           NaN        0        0        0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011-02-01           NaN        1        1        0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

To further investigate the case, run `left_t.info()` and `right_t.info()`,
then the same for both your original DataFrames (*left* and *right*).

Compare respective infos, looking for any differences in e.g. **index**
should be of *DatetimeIndex type*.

Compare also `left_t.columns` with analogous printout for your original
*left* DataFrame. Both of them should be of *Index* type (not *MultiIndex*).

Actually, the extra empty row after the title row in your printouts raises
suspicions that there must be something wrong with your original DataFrames.